# Add a value to AD note attribute after modifciation

Tags: c#, c, active-directory

I am trying to modify a value before I add it to an Active directory attribute Note "Ldap Representation is Info"
The idea is to look for the | and then do a return line example: USA|France|Algeria it will be :
USA
France
Algeria

here is my code :

```cs
//Initialize Notes/info in AD
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributeNameForInfo))
{
    string infoFromPerson = owner.GetAttributeValue(attributeNameForInfo).ToSafeNullableString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(infoFromPerson))
    {
        string info = infoFromPerson.Replace("|", "\n");

        TdnfTrace.Current.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 112233,
            "Custom AD RET : generating info value for " +
             owner.Login + " info : " + info);
        if (parameters != null && parameters.Keys.Contains("info"))
        {
            parameters["info"] = info;
        }
        else if (parameters != null && !parameters.Keys.Contains("info"))
        {
            parameters.Add("info", info);
        }
    }
    else
        TdnfTrace.Current.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 112233,
            "Custom AD RET : info value is null for " +owner.Login );
}
```

But it's not working as it should. I am still getting the infos in Active directory like this USA FRANCE ALGERIA it only takes off the "|"

I have seen in some fora that I could use `Set-ADUser username -Replace @{info='New info for the notes field'}`

Can you please help ?
Thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: Sorry Andreas just a small mistake.

Comment: If it's a mistake, then fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have solved the problem I guess by adding "\r" before the "\n"

`string info = infoFromPerson.Replace("|", "\r\n");`